# node.js - I can send a html page to the server but not an image?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So the user's data is sent to /menus along with the html page for menus itself. So my question is : why can't I send images? my menus.html has some images that won't load (market, credits, etc). How come the images on menus.html are not loaded when the page itself is sent?

Front end :

```
<form id="reg" action="/menus" method="post"> 
       <p><i>Username :</i></p>
       <input type="username" id="usr" class="form-control" name="name">

       <p><i>Password :</i></p>
       <input type="password" id="pwd" class="form-control" name="pwd">

       <br>
       <button id="submit_reg" class="btn btn-success"><i>Register</i></button>

</form>
```

Back end :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');
});

app.post('/menus', function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/menus/main.png');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/menus/create_new_painting.png');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/menus/gallery.png')
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/menus/market.png');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/menus/credits.png');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/menus/menus.html');
});
```

Comment: With the above code you'll basically send **one** connected file consisting of 2 html files and 4pngs. HTTP works slightly different. Maybe look for static bindings.

Comment: When I click on the submit button, I send 1 html and 5 images. The same html NEEDS these images. After all, it will look ugly without them.

Comment: I am not an expert in node.js but I would like to know why this doesn't work

Comment: Your problem is currently not nodejs, but HTTP. HTTP will send a separate request for each file (html, img, video, ...) it needs to display the page. You have to react on each of those request and not just send all parts over at once.

Comment: And how exactly?

Comment: Your code already looks like you're using expressjs. So take my advice from the first comment and use `app.static()`.

Comment: isnt it express.static()?

Comment: Basically both, but you can do a little research on your own ,-) https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: What if I say I have read that but still don't know what to do? Not enough examples. I learn from examples

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=express+static+tutorial

Comment: How to use app.static() on menus? ....

Comment: how to load f.e one of the images?

Comment: Wait so I can send them one by one if I include the static thing